# Use Dynamic content

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic-content

I have a master DE with all interest, permissions etc. This is also an attribute group. I want to use a field in this master DE as a value for dynamic content.  
I use a different DE to send the email to. This one is filled via an automation based on synchronized DEs.

I get this error:

> There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service
> representative. Error 1: Script IF Statement Invalid
> An error
> occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner
> exception for detail. Script Expression: [PNBA] MemberID: 100003369
> JobID: 0 An unrecognized expression appears in a script block. Script
> Expression: [PNBA] MemberID: 100003369 JobID: 0 
> Invalid Content:
>
> IF (([PNBA] == false)) THEN]%%
> %%=BeginImpressionRegion("01_Rule_1_NieuweVerdienmodellen_GeenPNBA")=%%
> %%=ContentBlockById("265218")=%% %%=EndImpressionRegion()=%% %%[

The AMPscript that is generated by the dynamic content is this:

```
%%[IF (([PNBA] == false)) THEN]%% 
%%=BeginImpressionRegion("01_Rule_1_NieuweVerdienmodellen_GeenPNBA")=%% 
%%=ContentBlockById("265218")=%% %%=EndImpressionRegion()=%% 
%%[ELSE]%% %%[ENDIF]%%
```

This AMPscript doesn't seem right? Is it not possible to retract dynamic content from a different DE thant the sending DE? Do I need to use AMPscript for that?

Comment: if the field is not in your sending DE you will need to use a lookup() ampscript functions

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, but note that it will only work if the `PNBA` field in your data Extension is of boolean type:

```
%%[IF AttributeValue("PNBA") == false THEN]%% 
%%=BeginImpressionRegion("01_Rule_1_NieuweVerdienmodellen_GeenPNBA")=%% 
%%=ContentBlockById("265218")=%% 
%%=EndImpressionRegion()=%% 
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Source: https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue/